# casting a result pointer of a pointer-returning-function to a reference, passable to another function as parameter

Tags: c

having the following:

```
char* function1(char* parameter)
        {
          printf("%c",*parameter);
        }
char* function2(char* sequence)
        {
          return *sequence;
        }
int main()
        {
          char* sequence = malloc(1);
          *sequence = 'a';
          function1(function2(sequence));
         }
```

The program run is rightfully giving a segmentation fault, since the call of function2 returns a pointer, and the function1 call needs a reference to be pointed at by its pointer parameter.

is there a way to cast the pointer returned from function2 to a reference while being passed as a parameter to function1?

Comment: When you dereference a char* you get a single char. Not quite sure why you would return a char* at function2 then.

Comment: No - you lost it when you dereferenced with 'return *sequence;'

Comment: Pay attention to compiler error messages; if you don't see any then you need to adjust your compiler settings.  (Don't ignore this)

Comment: If you paid attention to the warnings your compiler is giving you, you'd quickly realize what you are doing is nonsensical. (For GCC, always use `gcc -Wall -Werror`)

Comment: thank you guys, something I never thought of before (function return is dereferenced the same as parameter passing). problem solved... :D

Comment: Compilers don't (normally) give segmentation faults.  The compiler gives error messages, or your program experiences a segmentation fault when you run it.

Comment: @aschepler I edited accordingly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
char* function1(char* parameter)
{
    printf("%c", *parameter);
    return parameter;
}
char* function2(char* sequence)
{
    return sequence;
}
int main()
{
    char* sequence = (char*)malloc(1);
    *sequence = 'a';
    function1(function2(sequence));
}
```

You can also use your compiler to spot some errors. 
`function2()` must return a char* but you are dereferencing it right when you return which gets you a single char.
Furtermore `function1()` doesn't return a value neither.

Comment: so this is what the following warning has been telling me: test.c|7|warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|

Comment: @AlyShmahell right, that's what I was saying: it warns you about the fact that you are implicitly casting a character to a pointer to a character, which is likely to segfault.

Comment: the mention of integer in the warning got me into thinking it wasn't the issue, but thinking about it now, a pointer to a character is in fact a hexadecimal value and I was pointing at it...

Answer (score 1):

Your function2 is returning a value not the address however function1 is thinking of that value as address and trying to access it. hence you are getting segfault. function2 should return pointer but in your case you are returning *sequence instead of pointer

Comment: aaaalright, back on track. I never thought function return works the same as parameter passing in regards to pointers! thank you :)